# geom_density yields +50 warnings messages

Tags: r, histogram, density-plot

I'm trying to superimpose a density plot on top of a histogram. My code is bellow.

```
df = read_excel(file.choose(), range = cell_cols("F"))
df1 = data.frame(df) 
dfclean = df1[!is.na(df1)]
dff = data.frame(dfclean)

labq = seq(0, 950, 50)

ggplot(data = dff, aes(x = as.factor(1:dim(dff)[1]), y = dfclean)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat ='identity', fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_density() +
  ggtitle('Chi-quadradas com 4 gl') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = 'Observações', y = 'Valor obtido') +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=labq, labels=as.character(labq))
```

However, this produces the `There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)` error, all the while not returning the desired plot (only the histogram shows up). What do I do?

Comment: Depends on what the warnings were! Can you post them too?

Comment: `1: Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad
2: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.`
All of the warnings below the second one were its copy.

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible.  Could you include (some of) `df` in the question code, using `dput(df)`?  I'd guess the problem is that you're trying to compute the density for a factor, but I'm not sure:  your code before that looks very weird.

Comment: `> head(dff)
     dfclean
1 6.95760730
2 0.14415181
3 1.06780841
4 0.31793895
5 0.18396126
6 0.04523075`

Comment: Also, `> dput(df)
structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))`